# Python web scraper of javascript Div table

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-crawler

I have a wholesale website (behind login) that I am trying to scrape inventory levels. I've created my python script and it is giving a 200 response for login.

I'm trying to figure out how to scrape the inventory. I'm 99% sure that it is javascript but even if it is I don't know how to return the data since it is in divs and not a table (and I don't want to return every div).

This is the html page source
https://jsfiddle.net/3t6vjyLx/1/
 `the code is in the jsfiddle---too large to post here`
When I inspect the element it is giving me  and then

What do I need to do to load the page fully in my Python script so that I am able to pull that product-count?

There will be 64 seperate product-counts (8 locations and 5 sizes each)... is there a way to have it saved in a table in a specific way so that it is sorted by size? Since this wasn't created with a table that makes it more difficult, but I want to learn how to do it.

Thanks!

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2MZV.png` This is the inspect of the element

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a library like `requests_html` to create an `HTMLSession()` that loads the javascript elements which you can then parse.

The code could look something like this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def get_html(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render()  # renders javascript html and stores it in {obj}.html.html
    return r.html.html
```

While this solution may not be the most elegant (web scraping rarely is), I believe it should be sufficient if you're only scraping a small amount of data.

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle there will be the source code

Comment: and now that I've done that is there a way to print the rendered html session so that I can find the divs that I need to scrape?

Comment: `page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")` if using Selenium